# Difference between data migration and simple function in Django

Tags: python, django

example from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#data-migrations

What is the benefit of writing a data migration and migrate it over writing a simple function to modify necessary data?

```
def combine_names(apps, schema_editor):
    # We can't import the Person model directly as it may be a newer
    # version than this migration expects. We use the historical version.
    Person = apps.get_model("yourappname", "Person")
        for person in Person.objects.all():
            person.name = "%s %s" % (person.first_name, person.last_name)
            person.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('yourappname', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(combine_names),
    ]
```

in this example we could just run the code below and run it.

```
from models import Person
for person in Person.objects.all():
            person.name = "%s %s" % (person.first_name, person.last_name)
            person.save()
```

Comment: How do you determine when to run your migration function? What if you have development and production servers? Which state is each instance in at any given time? Can you rollback migrations? Yes, you **really** want migrations to be automatically managed.

Comment: Data migrations are automatically executed when you run your migrations, at the right moment in the migration history. That's invaluable when you want a consistent deployment on your staging and production servers. You can define your own rollback function as the second argument to `RunPython`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that `RunPython` solves is being able to run code in a historical context and takes advantage of the knowledge of your historical models and previous schema edits.

Let's say you hit an error in the middle if your migration. Now you have some data that is migrated and other data that is not, and a much bigger problem on your hands. That's probably the biggest reason.

See the [RunPython](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/migration-operations/#runpython) docs. It also helps you do other things like reverse migrations and providing migration hints.

Comment: So can you revert a data migration?

Comment: Yes. That information is in the docs I linked. For convenience: "The reverse_code argument is called when unapplying migrations. This callable should undo what is done in the code callable so that the migration is reversible."

Comment: Thank you, I read the docs for RunPython and it actually all makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

It's for deploy purpose. Lot of times a team have standard process to deploy code changes using automated tools, so being able to apply the data changes in production also needs automation. You can't possibly do what you said by login into your production server, load a shell and run the code every time this happens. It breaks the deployment process and error-prone, if something bad happens, you don't remember what you have done.

However, if your deploy process has the step to run migrations and you just have the code in a migration file, you could apply it automatically, and you can track what has been applied. It's also testable to make sure the migration itself is not buggy.

Comment: So I'll take it as it is for standards mostly, but what is bugging my mind is the comment line in the code:

# We can't import the Person model directly as it may be a newer
# version than this migration expects. We use the historical version.

So technically it is not as same as importing the model itself.

Comment: well I just needed to look into the documentation for RunPython to understand the it runs the code in historical context.